# django and gurobi in docker have permission issues

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, gurobi

I am trying to create a docker image for Django + Gurobi.

- Container runs as root by default.
- Gurobi does not want to run as root since license is issued to non-root user.
- If switching to non-root, Django's python complains "attempt to write a read-only database"  using /db.sqlite3.
- chown+chmod just /apps, /db.sqlite3, and /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3 did not help.
- problem seems to go away if I chown and chmod 777 the entire container: bad idea

What is the solution? Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY . .
ADD data .

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV APP_USER=user32
ENV APP_HOME=/home/$APP_USER

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip 

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y inetutils-ping

RUN tar xvzf gurobi9.5.0_linux64.tar.gz
ENV GUROBI_HOME /gurobi950/linux64
RUN cd /gurobi950/linux64 && python setup.py install
RUN rm gurobi9.5.0_linux64.tar.gz

RUN groupadd -r $APP_USER && \
    useradd -r -g $APP_USER -d $APP_HOME -s /sbin/nologin -c "Docker image user" $APP_USER

    
ENV TZ 'America/Los_Angeles'
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean
        
#RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER $APP_HOME
#RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER /apps/
#RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER /data/
#RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER /gurobi950/
#RUN chown -R  $APP_USER:$APP_USER  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
#RUN chown -R  $APP_USER:$APP_USER  /db.sqlite3
#RUN chmod -R 777 /db.sqlite3
#RUN chmod -R 777 /apps
#RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.9
#RUN chmod -R 777 /gurobi950
#RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER /
#RUN chmod -R 777 /

ENV GRB_LICENSE_FILE /gurobi.lic
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gurobi950/linux64/lib
RUN /gurobi950/linux64/bin/gurobi_cl --version

WORKDIR /

# running migrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

USER $APP_USER

# gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "core.wsgi"]
```

Here's the error on navigating to the home page

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost/login/?next=/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
attempt to write a readonly database
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.9
Python Path:    
['/',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, commercial software like Gurobi does not let you run inside a Docker container. Please contact Gurobi support at https://support.gurobi.com to discuss alternatives.